# Reverse Engineering a Tamura Inverter Board

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, inverter, reverse-engineering, backlight

This is about the pin-out of 9-pin connector 1 of inverter board
Tamura HBL-0291, part of a Toshiba Tecra M2 laptop from the early
2000s (see images).  The controller chip on the inverter board is
labeled TH12A 4625.

Here is what I have done already:

- Googled for specs, to no avail.
- Contacted Tamura for specs, to no avail.
- Identified pins 1-3 (5V0), 4-6 (GND), 7 (ADJ: voltage-based,
  max. brightness at 1V).
- Operated the inverter board and backlight connected to the laptop
  mainboard:

  Measured the voltage at pins 8 and 9 on the main board connector
  when the backlight/display is on (4.6V) and when it is off (0V).

  But this does *not* mean that pins 8 or 9 are some kind of ENA pins:
  To switch off the backlight, the laptop completely switches off the
  voltage on pins 1-3 using a high-side MOS-FET.

  When changing brightness on the laptop, only the voltage on ADJ
  changes, nothing changes on pins 8 or 9.

  Checked pins 8 and 9 with a scope as well, nothing interesting going
  on, all DC.  No equipment available to check what exactly happens on
  these pins and in what order when the laptop switches on or off the
  backlight.
- Operated the inverter board and backlight stand-alone on a
  breadboard:

  The backlight operates fine both with 0V and 5V on pins 8 and 9.
  There is a small increase of backlight brightness when switching
  pins 8 and 9 from 0V to 5V.
- Traced the circuitry as far as possible of pins 8 and 9, both on the
  main board and on the inverter board (see sketch).  Q5 and Q6 are
  labelled G25, but I have not found any specs matching these clearly
  transistor-ish parts: With voltage of about 2V applied across 1-2
  the connection 3-2 drops resistance.

I would like to understand what these mysterious pins 8 and 9 are good
for to operate the backlight and inverter board as "originally as
possible" from a microcontroller.  (Using another inverter board is
not an option due to size restrictions.)

The best conclusion I could come to as a beginner is that these are
for "soft-startup" or "soft-shutdown" of the CCFL.  So to switch on
the backlight I would:

1. Apply 5V to pins 1-3 also using some high-side MOS-FET.
2. Wait for 5ms
3. Apply 3.3V to pin 9 using a GPIO pin
4. Wait for 5ms
5. Apply 3.3V to pin 8 using a GPIO pin

and to switch it off I would process above sequence in opposite order.

What do you think?

[image: Inverter Board Front]

[image: Inverter Board Front Close-Up]

[image: Inverter Board Back]

[image: Circuit Sketch]

Comment: Values of the resistors are 600 ohms, 1.6k, and 3.2k, right? That is close to powers of 2. Perhaps they are digitally controlled shunt resistor for monitoring CFL current?

Comment: You're right about the resistor values - forgot to use to American-style digits, sorry ... 

Regarding your proposal I have a follow-up (beginner) question, probably strangely posed: The part of the circuit shown above is pretty closed and self-contained on the PCB. The only connection out of it are the ones labeled "pin_8", "pin_9, "to controller IC". If these were digitally controlled shunts, the controller IC (or whatever monitoring entity) would also need to know the state of the shunts (on/off) to properly read the CFL current, right?

Comment: The controller probably compares the voltage across the shunt to the control voltage. Pins 8 and 9 reduce this value, so the controller then 'thinks' the current is lower and increases it. You say their effect is quite small compared to the brightness control, so I'm guessing they are used to dynamically fine tune the brightness for some purpose. You could probably just set these pins to fixed logic levels with no ill effect.